# Aggregation filter with must exists returns non existing fields

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, aggregation

I'm trying to run a aggregation query that looks like this

```
{
   "from": 0,
   "size": 1000,
    "query": {
        "constant_score": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "term": {
                                "metric_value_type.keyword": {
                                    "value": "Outage",
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "terms": {
                                "city.keyword": [
                                    "LONDON"
                                ],
                                "boost": 1
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "range": {
                                "metric_timestamp": {
                                    "from": "2019-08-01T08:30:00.000Z",
                                    "to": "2019-08-19T14:00:00.000Z",
                                    "include_lower": true,
                                    "include_upper": true,
                                    "boost": 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                    "boost": 1
                }
            },
            "boost": 1
        }
    },
    "aggregations": {
        "missing_metric_values_aggregation": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "metric_value"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "aggregations": {
                "groupby_aggregation": {
                    "terms": {
                        "field": "cpe_name.keyword",
                        "size": 20000,
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                        "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                        "order": [
                            {
                                "_count": "desc"
                            },
                            {
                                "_key": "asc"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my document looks like this

```
                    "customer_site_id": "BLABLA",
                    "link_id": null,
                    "cpe_type": "ROUTER",
                    "cpe_id": "BLABLA",
                    "metric_value_type": "Outage",
                    "metric_value_unit": "s",
                    "metric_timestamp": "2019-08-06T12:40:00.000Z",
                    "metric_time": "12:40:00",
                    "metric_value": null,
                    "cpe_name": "BLABLA",
                    "city": "LONDON",
                    "zip_code": null,
                    "address": "BLABLA",
                    "cpe_ip_address": "BLABLA",
                    "position": {
                        "lat": BLABLA,
                        "lon": BLABLA
                    }
```

The metric_value could either be null or have an integer value and when I'm running the query above I still get documents that has null in metric_value field, how come?

Is it because I have multiple field that starts with metric_value?

Comment: Your `must/exists` should be in the query part, not sure why you added it in the aggregation section, since that's only influencing aggregation results, not hits.

Answer (score 0):

A filter `exists` works only in the filter or bool query. It doesn't make sense in the aggregation.
You have to first get the correct data set after that any aggregation should be apply.
Try the below query, hope it will help.

```
{
"from": 0,
"size": 1000,
"query": {
    "constant_score": {
        "filter": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "metric_value"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "metric_value_type.keyword": {
                                "value": "Outage",
                                "boost": 1
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "terms": {
                            "city.keyword": [
                                "LONDON"
                            ],
                            "boost": 1
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "metric_timestamp": {
                                "from": "2019-08-01T08:30:00.000Z",
                                "to": "2019-08-19T14:00:00.000Z",
                                "include_lower": true,
                                "include_upper": true,
                                "boost": 1
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "adjust_pure_negative": true,
                "boost": 1
            }
        },
        "boost": 1
    }
},
"aggregations": {
    "missing_metric_values_aggregation": {
        "aggregations": {
            "groupby_aggregation": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "cpe_name.keyword",
                    "size": 20000,
                    "min_doc_count": 1,
                    "shard_min_doc_count": 0,
                    "show_term_doc_count_error": false,
                    "order": [
                        {
                            "_count": "desc"
                        },
                        {
                            "_key": "asc"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}